# why do i get this problem when i want to filter project

Tags: laravel

I want to add the translate feature to my website. but I got this problem

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: filterdata] [URI: {locale}/project/{filter}]
```

this is the app web route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect(app()->getLocale());
});
Route::get('/project', function () {
    return redirect(app()->getLocale());
});
Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{locale}', 
    'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'],
    'middleware' => 'setlocale',
], function(){
    Route::get('/', function(){
        return view('pages.home');
    })->name('home');
    Route::get('/project/{filter}', 'ProjectController@filterProject')->name('filterdata');
});
```

this is the blade project

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ url(app()->getLocale().'/project/Branding') }}" role="button">Branding</a>
```

this is the controller:

```
public function filterProject($locale, $filter){
        $locale = $locale;
        $filter = str_replace('-',' ',$filter);
        $url = Lang::get('proyek.project');
        $url2 = json_encode($url);
        $data = json_decode($url2, true);
        $data = array_filter($data);
        
        if(collect($data)->where('tag1',"{$filter}")->all() == true){
            $project = collect($data)->where('tag1',"{$filter}")->all();
        }elseif(collect($data)->where('tag2',"{$filter}")->all() == true){
            $project = collect($data)->where('tag2',"{$filter}")->all();
        }elseif(collect($data)->where('tag3',"{$filter}")->all() == true){
            $project = collect($data)->where('tag3',"{$filter}")->all();
        }else{
            $project = collect($data)->all();
        }
        return view ('pages/projects', compact('project','locale','filter'));
}
```

and this is the buttons I use for language switch:

```
<div class="form-check d-flex align-items-center">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input form-control" name="language" id="languageen" value="{{ route(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::currentRouteName(), 'en') }}" onchange="location = this.value;" @if(app()->getLocale() == 'en') checked @endif>
          <label class="form-check-label control-label" for="languageen">
            EN
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check d-flex align-items-center">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input form-control" name="language" id="languageid" value="{{ route(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::currentRouteName(), 'id') }}" onchange="location = this.value;" @if(app()->getLocale() == 'id') checked @endif>
          <label class="form-check-label control-label" for="languageid">
            ID
          </label>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you never passed `$filter` variable to your route, on the button element:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ url(app()->getLocale().'/project/Branding') }}" role="button">Branding</a>
```

As you can see, you're only passing `$locale` parameter. In order for this to work, you pass your `$filter` variable as well

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ url(app()->getLocale().'/project/Branding/' . $filter) }}" role="button">Branding</a>
```

If you don't need `$filter` every time when you're calling this route, you can make it optional, with the `?` operator:

```
Route::get('/project/{filter?}', 'ProjectController@filterProject')->name('filterdata');
```

Answer (score 0):

zlatan

"Branding" is a filter

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ url(app()->getLocale().'/project/Branding') }}" role="button">Branding</a>
```